# Parsing strings at compile-time - if possible

Tags: c++11, printf

I am trying to make compile time checks over the format of the printf. Here is the code.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename CHAR, typename ...ARGS>
constexpr size_t trace_cond(CHAR fmt, ARGS&&... args) {
   //always needs to pass
   return 1;
}

template <size_t N, typename ...ARGS>
constexpr size_t trace_cond(const char (&fmt)[N], ARGS&&... args) {
   //return parse(fmt) == args;
   return sizeof...(args) != 0;
}

#define TRACE(fmt, ...) { \
   static_assert(trace_cond(fmt, __VA_ARGS__), "Wrong ARGS"); \
   printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  //working fine
  TRACE("%d %d\n", 2, 3);

  const char* format = "%d %d\n";
  //error
  TRACE(format, 2, 3);
}
```

So when the format is known at compile time I want to have a check(using static_assert) and if it is not known then the check should be not called or always to pass

Obs:

- Currently the code is not compiling because `const char *format is not declared constexpr`
- The `main` should not be change because `TRACE` macro is used in a large codebase but changes to `TRACE` are more than welcome

So my question is:
Is there a way to skip static_assert or make it pass when `fmt` type is `const char *`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want by moving the `static_assert` to the `trace_cond`

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t C, typename CHAR>
size_t trace_cond(CHAR fmt) {
    //always needs to pass
    return 1;
}

template <typename ...ARGS>
constexpr size_t count_args(ARGS&&... args) {
    return sizeof...(args);
}

template <size_t C, size_t N>
constexpr size_t trace_cond(const char (&fmt)[N]) {
    // TODO, parse fmt and do the needed checks
    static_assert(C == 3, "");
    return 1;
}

#define TRACE(fmt, ...) { \
    trace_cond<count_args(__VA_ARGS__)>(fmt); \
    printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Static check - hard coded to check for 3 arguments
    TRACE("%d %d %d\n", 2, 3, 4);

    const char* format = "%d %d\n";
    // No checks performed
    TRACE(format, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it would not work, because inside function `trace_cond` it is not a `constexpr` so it could not be parsed.